# How to correctly import aave/flashloan-box in Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, flash-loans, aave

I was following the [step-by-step](https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/flash-loans#step-by-step) guide, and since there is only the main code, I've tried with the following imports

```solidity
pragma solidity 0.6.12;  
import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";  
import { ILendingPool } from "https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/ILendingPool.sol";  
import { ILendingPoolAddressesProvider } from "https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol";  
import { IERC20 } from "https://github.com/alcueca/ERC3156/blob/main/contracts/ERC20.sol";  
/**   
!!!  
Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanReceiverBase contract as they could be   
exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.  
!!!  
 */  
contract MyV2FlashLoan is FlashLoanReceiverBase {  
 /**  
This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount  
*/  
    function executeOperation(  
        address[] calldata assets,  
        uint256[] calldata amounts,  
        uint256[] calldata premiums,  
        address initiator,  
        bytes calldata params  
    )  
    external  
    override  
    returns (bool)  
    {  
        //  
        // This contract now has the funds requested.  
        // Your logic goes here.  
        //  
        
        // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes  
        // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.  
        // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay  
        // these amounts.  
        
        // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount  
        for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {  
            uint amountOwing = amounts[i].add(premiums[i]);  
            IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);  
        }  
        
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

But when I try to compile (with remix) there is the following error

```
not found https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelincontracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the problem is that the [`Remix` branch of the aave/flashloan-box repo](https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/) that you're using appears to require OpenZeppelin 3.x but is importing the latest version instead.

One of the breaking changes in [OpenZeppelin v4.0.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v4.0.0) was the reorganization of the `contracts/` directory. In particular, `SafeERC20.sol` was moved to the `utils/` subdirectory. flashloan-box imports a bleeding edge OpenZeppelin version but still expects the file to be under the old path. If you visit the URL from the import, you can see that this path gives you a HTTP 404 error: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol.

This is not a problem when you're just installing packages locally where versions can be controlled via `package.json`. In fact, [flashloan-box](https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/b9a4af3797d3c37ef40db45dcb9a4084cd189a07/package.json#L14) has a proper dependency on OpenZeppelin 3.x so you'd have no problem using it with Truffle, which seems to be the way recommended by the README. In the `Remix` branch this does not work. The version requirement should have been embedded in the import and it was not. This looks like a bug and I think you should [report it in the project](https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/issues/new). The fix would involve replacing the import inside `FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol` with a URL to a specific tagged version of OpenZeppelin or a [NPM import with the `@` syntax to specify version](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import.html#import-from-npm). Alternatively, the project could switch to OpenZeppelin 4.x but it will likely require a non-trivial amount of work.

The fix has to be applied by the project developers. In the meantime, to get your project working in Remix you'd have to clone flashloan-box or add its contracts directly to your own project and apply the fix there. Personally, I'd recommend just switching to a framework in this case, especially if this is just a tutorial project and you do not have a big codebase to migrate. Remix is geared towards making it very quick and easy to start developing but locally you have access to more powerful tools for dependency management. If you have some special requirements and need more control, like in this case, a framework is often a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Which framework would you suggest, truffle?

Comment: It's up to personal preference and the languages you like to work with. If you like JS, use Truffle or Hardhat, if Python then Brownie and if you want to write tests in pure Solidity then dapptools or foundry. But in this case I'd recommend Truffle simply because that's what the flashloan-box supports out of the box so you'll probably have the easiest time with it.